# How to skip on an if statement in scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

I have the following function to do a recursive countdown in scheme:

```
(define (countdown n)
   (display n)
   (if (> n 0)
      (countdown (- n 1))
       0 ; how to make this "do nothing" and *not* print zero?
    )
)
```

And a run of it:

```
(countdown 7)
(countdown 6)
765432100
65432100
```

You'll notice that after the countdown has finished, it prints the zero (or maybe it 'evaluates' to zero). How can I get rid of that so it only prints "7654321" and then exits ?

Additionally, if I try and put both statements inside the `if`:

```
(define (countdown n)
   (if (> n 0) (
      (display n)
      (countdown (- n 1)))
       0
    )
)
(countdown 7)
```

I get the following error:

```
7654321TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Current Eval Stack:
-------------------------
0: (countdown (- n 1))
1: (countdown (- n 1))
2: (countdown (- n 1))
3: (countdown (- n 1))
4: (countdown (- n 1))
5: (countdown (- n 1))
6: (countdown 7)
```

What does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The First Program

The `countdown` procedure *always* prints its argument, since `(display n)` occurs first in the procedure. When `n` is zero, it is printed in that call, then the `if` expression checks whether `n` is zero. That explains why `0` is printed the first time.

`0` is printed for a second time, not by the program, but by the REPL. You are running the program in the REPL (Read Evaluate Print Loop) when you invoke it by calling `(countdown 7)` in the REPL. The REPL evaluates the expressions, and prints the results *in the REPL*. The last expression of the `countdown` procedure is returned from the procedure, to the REPL, which kindly prints it out for you. Because it is a REPL, doing what REPLs do. If you ran this program as a script from the command line you would not see this last zero.

Now, a stylistic note: do not leave hanging parentheses in lisps. It is unidiomatic to do so, and it gets harder to read lisp code with such errant parentheses when code gets larger. There are some rare cases when it is appropriate, but generally you should collect closing parenths together.

A first attempt to fix up the posted code might look like:

```
(define (countdown n)
  (if (> n 0)
      (begin (display n)
             (countdown (- n 1)))
      0))
```

Here the `begin` form is needed because `if` only evaluates *one* expression for each of its arms, and two expressions need to be evaluated to print `n` and recursively call `countdown`. This program will print `0` once in the REPL (because it is still returning `0`), and not at all in a command-line script.

The `countdown` procedure is *still* returning a number, which the REPL is still printing. Procedures always return values in Scheme, so something will have to be returned from `countdown`, no matter what. One could punt and just omit the second arm of the `if` form:

```
(define (countdown n)
  (if (> n 0)
      (begin (display n)
             (countdown (- n 1)))))
```

This is perfectly legal Scheme, but the `if` form returns an *unspecified* value when its first test evaluates to `#f` and the second arm has been omitted. When I ran this in Chez Scheme, the unprintable value `#<void>` was returned, so the behavior is exactly what OP is expecting.

But there may be a better way to write this; many Schemes (Chez Scheme, for one) have a `when` form that only tests one expression, i.e., `when` is one-armed. `when` also returns unspecified values when its single test evaluates to `#f`. But, `when` has an added advantage, in that it can evaluate multiple expressions when the test evaluates to true; this means that the `begin` form is not needed when using `when`:

```
(define (countdown n)
  (when (> n 0)
    (display n)
    (countdown (- n 1))))
```

This works as desired in the REPL:

```
> (countdown 7)
7654321>
```

### The Second Program

```
(define (countdown n)
  (if (> n 0)
      ((display n)
       (countdown (- n 1)))
      0))
```

As already mentioned, `if` evaluates *one* expression per arm. We have already seen that expressions can be grouped together by using a `begin` form. Here an attempt is made to combine two expressions by grouping them with parentheses, but this won't work. In short, parentheses carry semantic meaning in lisps, and one cannot arbitrarily add them wherever one likes.

In Scheme a form that looks like `(something something-else-1 ...)` is interpreted as a procedure call, unless `something` is bound as a syntactic keyword (i.e., unless `something` is a macro identifier). Procedure calls always evaluate their operator expressions and all of their argument expressions in an unspecified order. Since the order of evaluation depends on the implementation, the detailed behavior will vary, but consider:

```
((display n) (countdown (- n 1)))
```

When `(display n)` is evaluated (at which point `n` is evaluated and `display` is evaluated, in unspecified order, and the results are used to make a procedure call), the result of the call is to return an unspecified value, and to cause a side effect, i.e., the printing of the value of `n`. `display` is a procedure that always *returns* an unspecified value.

When the expression `(countdown (- n 1))` is evaluated, control will pass to the next recursive call, with `n` diminished by 1 each time, until `n` is 0. At this point, `0` is returned to the previous call, `((display 1) (countdown 0))`, so that we now have `((display 1) 0)`.

`(display n)` may not have been evaluated yet in any of the forms; this is the case in Chez Scheme. So in that case, `((display  1) 0)` --> `(#<some-unspecified-value> 0)` with the side-effect now of printing `1`. It should be clear that attempting to use the procedure `#<some-unspecified-value>` is not the path to joy.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Alternatively, the Scheme implementation might evaluate the operator expression before the argument expressions, in which case the count-down numbers will all have been printed before encountering the error. OP shows `7654321` preceding the error message, which seems to indicate that this is the behavior in OP's Scheme.

Comment: holy cow this is such a fantastic answer. I wish all programming languages had such dedicated answerers as yourself -- cheers!

Comment: also, is the `(begin ...)` conceptually similar to the braces in c? For example an `if` statement expects one expression, but if you add braces, you can have compound expressions within the `if` ?

Comment: Sort of, but I'd be careful with that comparison. In C braces can create a _compound statement_, which is what is happening with `if (expression) statement;`. A _statement_ can be a compound statement, according to the C grammar. So in this sense braces are a little bit like `begin`. But, braces introduce a new scoping region for variables in C, and `begin` does not do that. When used in a place where a single expression is expected, a `begin` form evaluates the contained expressions in order, and the entire form is treated as one expression.